# CORS Stripe React Tutorial

Tags: reactjs, cors, stripe-payments

I get the following error when using Stripe in React. I'm assuming my server is set-up right. So how do I resolve an Access-Contorl-Allow-Origin error?

```
> Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:9000/charge' from origin
> 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
> mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

  async submit(ev) {
  let {token} = await this.props.stripe.createToken({name: "Name"});
  let response = await fetch("http://localhost:9000/charge", {
     method: "POST",
     headers: {"Content-Type": "text/plain"},
     mode: "no-cors",
     body: token.id
   });
 if (response.ok) this.setState({complete: true});
 }
```

This is the tutorial I'm following... https://stripe.com/docs/recipes/elements-react

As a follow up, the error was resolved using one of their test credit cards...
https://stripe.com/docs/testing

Comment: Are you sure you have CORS set up properly? The error says it didn't get a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in response. You can try and set it to `*` in the beginning when you are just testing.

Comment: If your applications is hosted in IIS Server 8+, you may remove OPTIONSVerbHandler from web.config file.

Comment: I tried setting up the headers like this... 
headers: {"Content-Type": "text/plain", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"},

Answer (score 0):

The error speaks for itself. Your express server (I assume you follow the tutorial and your backend is written in `express`) has not been configured to handle CORS properly.

The idea behind `CORS` is that if the browser request resource from a different domain, it needs to be given the permission to do so by this resource itself.

For `express`, you can either use the `cors` middleware to handle `cors` properly, or do it yourself as so in the link here: https://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html

Comment: I tried adding the below code to the server.js file however it didn't work. I'm going to try cors middleware. 
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

Comment: @Thai , for those of us less familiar with CORS, could you explain how to configure `cors` properly. Suggesting that we do so without showing *how* to do so isn't super helpful.